# SwiftUI - passing Binding to NSViewRepresentable causes memory leaks and app slowdown

Tags: macos, swiftui

I noticed that our macOS app written in SwiftUI becomes slower and slower as the user is using it.
Digging into it, I found that SwiftUI keeps allocating small blocks of memory that are never released (and I think it's causing some unnecessary work too).

I isolated a simple macOS app that demonstrates the issue.
**Sample app**: [download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0iknum72zjji5nl/Memory-Growth.zip?dl=0).

The bug seems to be linked to adding a `NSViewRepresentable` view in SwiftUI hierarchy and passing to it a `Binding` to the SwiftUI View's state.
Every time the state of SwiftUI view is modified, a small block of memory is allocated that is never released.
In the sample app, I just added a timer that updates the state every 10ms to better highlight the issue.

**Am I right to believe it's a SwiftUI bug?**
Looking at my code, I don't think I'm doing anything illegal, do I?

[image]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var point: CGPoint = .zero
    @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.01, tolerance: nil, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.blue.frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .overlay(Text("\(point.x)"))
            .onSomeExternalAction(someValue: $point)
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                point = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random() % 100), y: 0.0)
            }
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class _MouseTrackingView: NSView {
   // Just a dummy view   
}

struct MouseTrackingView: NSViewRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewType = _MouseTrackingView
    
    let someValue: Binding<CGPoint>? // Binding is retained here!

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> _MouseTrackingView {
        return _MouseTrackingView()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: _MouseTrackingView, context: Context) {
        //...
    }
    
}

extension View {
    
    public func onSomeExternalAction(someValue: Binding<CGPoint>?) -> some View {
        self
            .background(MouseTrackingView(someValue: someValue))
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Similar to an Apple dev forums post. I spent two WWDC labs with engineers on the subject of chasing similar growth unrecognized by the memory debugger and without traces in Allocations. What does Allocations and Leaks have to say about your demo app?

Comment: No leaks are detected but every time a view updates, a small block of memory is allocated in system's framework. And it just keeps climbing...

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?  I am noticing a similar behavior.

Comment: @alionthego I did not unfortunately. I might reach out for Apple’s dev Technical support in the future to ask about that. But if you find any more information about the issue, please let me know!